# Android Studio SQLite Error: "no such column.."

Tags: android, sqlite

When my application is creating the database, it seems to not be creating the column 'cardname'. I've been looking through my code but can't find what I've done wrong. Can anyone help me please ?

**DBAdapter class**

```
public class DBAdapter {
static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
static final String KEY_USERNAME = "name";
static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
static final String KEY_CARDNUM = "cardnum";
static final String KEY_CARDNAME = "cardname";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CPDB";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Users";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table Users (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "name text not null,"
                  +"password text not null,"
                   +"cardnum text not null,"
                    + "cardname text not null"
                      + ");";


final Context context;

DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter (Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version" + oldVersion + "to" + newVersion + "which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users");
        onCreate (db);

    }
}
```

**The query inside the DBAdapter class**

```
  //--retrieves cards for the user--
public Cursor getCards(String username) throws SQLException{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_CARDNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "= '" + username + "'", null, null, null, null,null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

**Main Activity Class (When the error occurs) ..**

```
  if (view.getId() == R.id.bttn_show)
    {
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_username);
        String tesco = "tesco";

        DBAdapter db= new DBAdapter(this);

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getCards(username.getText().toString());

    ArrayList<String> usersCards = new ArrayList<>();

    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String aCard = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("cardname"));
            usersCards.add(aCard);

        } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    if (usersCards.contains(tesco)) {
        ImageButton tb1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_1);

        tb1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tesco);

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Add a Card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Logcat error log**

```
        --------- beginning of crash
02-07 13:13:08.100    2109-2109/com.cardpocket.cardpocket E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.cardpocket.cardpocket, PID: 2109
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at         com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
 



 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:     cardname (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, name, cardname FROM Users WHERE name= 'cliff'
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnecti    on.java:889)
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>    (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.    java:44)
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
        at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
        at com.cardpocket.cardpocket.DBAdapter.getCards(DBAdapter.java:148)
        at     com.cardpocket.cardpocket.mainactivity.onClick(mainactivity.java:78)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post more code please? update dabase version 11

Comment: are you using right column name in your `KEY_CARDNAME`?

Comment: what do you mean ved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to get cardesc column which is not created in your DBAdapter class. Can you post more logcat log?

Comment: I apologize, that was from an old log. I have updated all the code. Again i apologize.

Comment: Not sure. Try increasing your database version to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a record named "tesco" in the table.

Try searching the tesco after you have inserted the tesco into the table.

Comment: no, it cannot add it into the table as it thinks that the column 'cardname' does not exist.